# Why is my javascript function completely ignored? (Very simple example)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons. Save and undo. They execute a javascript, and in the end they call `resetButtons()` which is meant to disable the buttons until any other change in the users input occurs. This code has worked for over a year now, but while implementing some new features, this one has broken.

Here is a direct snippet of code:

```
function undo(){
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel your inputs?");
    if (r == true) {
        setLoadedValues();  //calls in the cached previous values
        updateAllBoxValues();  //updates view
        console.log("before resetting buttons");
        resetButtons();
        console.log("after resetting buttons");
    }
}

function resetButtons(){
    console.log("resetting buttons");
    $(".save").addClass("disabled");
    $('.save').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $(".undo").addClass('disabled');
    $('.undo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    console.log("done resetting buttons");
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
before resetting buttons
after resetting buttons
```

I have suspected some wrong formatting with brackets, but this is a direct snippet of code, and if `undo()` works, so should `resetButtons()`, right? Also, I should have been given a **undefined function**, or an *unexpecetd end of input* or something similar if that was the case. The call to resetButtons is also ignored when I click the save button. I am lost. Help?

Comment: @kiks73 I think the point is that `resetButtons()` appears to not be being run.  The console log shows the lines being logged before and after the function call, but not either of the lines _within_ the function itself.

Comment: Are the functions defined as you posted, or far away from each other, in different contexts? Can you recreate the behaviour in a plunkr/jsfiddle?

Comment: Set a breakpoint before it calls `resetButtons`, and then type `resetButtons` in the console to see what it shows.

Comment: I suspect you have a redefinition of the function somewhere.

Comment: Nice one! :) No console log on calling `resetButtons` no logging output from that function, no undefined error. Check if you have on the code another function with same name that can be in same scope.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar my testings of your code are performing as it should

Comment: Try to duplicate the function **resetButtons** with **foo** name and try to call this on **undo**, I suspect you have a redefinition of the function

Comment: any chance you have an element called undo / or resetButtons?

Comment: @doldt, the functions are sequential, exactly like posted. I think you guys might be on to something with the redefinition thing. Let me try to rename the function to something more specific. The file I'm editing does not contain a duplicate function, but I use a few includes...

Comment: @kiks73 that is not true at all. when functions execute syncronous code there's no need for callbacks lol.

Comment: You guys. Awesome. It was a double named function. This is like Columbus and the standing egg; just so obvious when I first got the idea from you. The buttons have been buggy since a new tabbed pane was introduced a couple of months ago, I just haven't noticed it until now. I believe @Barmar was the first. Please write up an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a duplicate function definition. Rename one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine, you must have some other error somewhere else (like a function named like those two).

By the way, I suggest using jQuery's "prop" method to change the disabled attribute:

```
$('foo').prop('disabled', true);

$('foo').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: @KjetilNordin I have amended the first paragraph to reflect that is a tip.

Comment: ...and I have removed my downvote. I still think you stole the actual answer from the comments, so I'll give answering credits to someone else ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try triggering the resetButton() function in console, if there's an issue it should return it. Testing it in a random console gives all the logs it should, but I can't vouch for the selectors. The error is probably elsewhere in the code.

Comment: This is also a very good answer, and a more general approach to fix a number of possible issues with my symptoms. I actually didn't know I could call functions from the console (I mostly use Chrome's debugging and inspectin tools), but it displayed the function, and it was clearly not the one I was trying to call :)